# Can custom 3D models be imported into FUZE4?

Tags: nintendo-switch, fuze4

I have just discovered there is a Nintendo Switch title that is a game development platform, called [FUZE4](https://www.fuze.co.uk/nintendo-switch.html). It serves as an introduction to programming for young or inexperienced people who want to learn to code games, and is based on a "python-like" programming language. From what I've gathered so far, it looks promising.

I can create any 3D assets I desire in [Blender](https://www.blender.org) (on my computer), but is it possible to import those 3D models into FUZE4 (for Switch)?

(Blender can [export to various formats](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/import_export.html), including .obj and .3ds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not import ANY assets as Nintendo doesn't want to have uncensored access to their console. I was just thinking of getting Fuze, but this limitation is really annyoing, so I don't know if it's worth it.
It includes a sprite and a map editor, so you can create this on your own, but you can't create Sounds or 3D objects.

Comment: Thanks! Game Builder Garage suffers from this limitation too. But yes, you can draw pixely sprites in it. So somebody wanting to make "inappropriate" content can only make *amateurish* inappropriate content. Can only make amateurish looking content, period. For people all about the coding, maybe it doesn't matter. But for an artist who wants to bring their art to life through games, this limitation makes it a no-go. I feel like community moderation and a reputation system would be a better way to keep content kid-friendly than excluding the ability to import custom assets. IMO...

Comment: This is a general problem with creative Switch games which are not really games but more about content creation. There is also a synthesizer software available, but of course it suffers the same limitation, so you can only play on the console, but no importing or exporting.